# Ransack search for far away tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I want to search orders by tags, but tags are associated with customers.... is it possible to do that with Ransack?

Order.rb

```
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :customer
 ....
```

Customer.rb

```
Class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :orders
has_many :customers_tags
has_many :tags, through: :customers_tags
 ....
```

Tag.rb

```
Class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :customers_tags
has_many :customers, through: :customers_tags
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search through multiple associations. Just reference them as you would in the association name (plural for `has_many`, singular for `belongs_to`).

So in your example, searching for a field `fieldname`, you would use:

`customer_tags_fieldname_cont`

(Replace `fieldname` with whatever field you want to search.)

Comment: Like `Customer.ransack(customer_tags_fieldname_cont: params["fieldname"])`  ?